# Merge the lines between triple single quotes and then replace the starting quote with '#'

Tags: python

```
'''
Created on Mar 11, 2017

@author: XXZ
This file is to demonstrate the word frequency counter. This is a very 
important practical

'''
```

Required Output:

```
#Created on Mar 11, 2017 @author: XXZ This file is to demonstrate the word frequency counter. This is a very important practical
```

(I want to count it as a comment)

My Code:
    import re

```
START_PATTERN = "'''\n"
END_PATTERN = "'''\n"

with open('counter.py') as file:
    match = False
    newfile = None
for line in file:
    if re.match(START_PATTERN, line):
        match = True
        newfile = open('my_new_file.txt', 'w')
        continue
    elif re.match(END_PATTERN, line):
        match = False
        newfile.close()
        continue
    elif match:
        newfile.write(line)
        newfile.write('\n')
```

This just writes the last multilines comment in the file. Not all.

Comment: What have you tried, and what are you stuck on?

Comment: Why is the output expecting a split before the word frequency counter?

Comment: Its not split, its supposed to be all in the same line.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Unlike docstrings, comments aren't available to `help` etc.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have to count the number of comments in files.

Comment: So if you just want to count, you wouldn't have to replace (and definitely not to save in a new file), but perhaps could just calculate the length of the result of a `re.findall`, which matches all kinds of comments...?

Comment: Well there are lots of task related to the comments of the file. I need to count the number of comments, then I need to extract only the comments and save it in different file.

Comment: They aren't just comments. They're docstrings. Maybe adding some real context to the question would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the whole file in and apply an `re.sub` in multiline mode.
Afterwards (or before, doesn't mater...) just crop those three `'` and add `#`:

```
import re
with open('test.py', 'r') as f:
    txt = f.read()
    print('IN:\n', txt)
    txt = re.sub('\n', ' ', txt, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    txt = '#' + txt[3:-3]
    print('\nOUT:\n',txt)


IN:
 '''
Created on Mar 11, 2017

@author: XXZ
This file is to demonstrate the word frequency counter. This is a very 
important practical

'''

OUT:
 # Created on Mar 11, 2017  @author: XXZ This file is to demonstrate the word frequency counter. This is a very  important practical
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Can you explain the "flags = re.MULTILINE"

Comment: Normally `re` works on a line by line base, so you just can't match newlines. This mode makes `re` handle the complete text as one block. See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub` to replace *one or more* new-lines (`\n`) with a singular space. Then strip the result (of any trailing and leading spaces) and concatenate that onto a `'#'`:

```
import re
'#' + re.sub('\n+',' ',s).strip()
#'#Created on Mar 11, 2017 @author: XXZ This file is to demonstrate the word frequency counter. This is a very  important practical'
```

Comment: Correct, even if I'd replace `'\n'` by `'\s'`, so that two lines do not stick too close together...

Comment: It doesn't concatenate the lines in one line.

Comment: @nehaj see the answer now; is it not exactly the same as your desired?

Comment: it puts the '#' in front of each line. But doesn't concatenate the lines into one.

Comment: No it doesnt, it gets rid of all lines so by definition the result is only one line

Answer (score 0):

Replace `\n` with . Here is a code:

```
a = '''
Created on Mar 11, 2017

@author: XXZ
This file is to demonstrate the word frequency counter. This is a very 
important practical

'''

print("#"+a.replace("\n"," "))
```

Output:

```
# Created on Mar 11, 2017  @author: XXZ This file is to demonstrate the word frequency counter. This is a very  important practical
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.join`

**Ex:**

```
s = '''
Created on Mar 11, 2017

@author: XXZ
This file is to demonstrate the word frequency counter. This is a very 
important practical

'''
print("# "+ " ".join(i.strip() for i in s.split()) )
```

**Output:**

```
# Created on Mar 11, 2017 @author: XXZ This file is to demonstrate the word frequency counter. This is a very important practical
```